# How to make an interactive calculator for any mathematical relation?

Tags: dynamic, physics, interactive, input

I am wondering if there is a way to make a calculator for any relation that is interactive.
First, I choose a relation with some variables in it.
The user will input a value for all of the variables except for the one they wish to solve for.
Some of the equations/relations I interested in applying this program to are the following physics equations (though there are many more present):

- Voltage=Current*Resistance
- Charge=Capacitance*Voltage
- Density=Mass/Volume
- Velocity=Distance/Speed

All of these involve only three variables but more complex relations should also be able to programmed into an interactive interface such as:

- (final velocity)^2=(velocity at time 0)^2+2*acceleration*displacement
- Impedance=Sqrt(Ressistance^2+(Inductive reactance-Capacitative
- reactance)^2) Magnetic Field=Permittivity of free Space *Number of
  coils * Current/Length of solenoid

My goal is take any relation and create a simple program where the user can input values into all of the fields except for one which they leave blank. The program will then solve for that value. I contacted Wolfram Support for help and they said I had to pay to Technical Consulting if I wanted to develop such a program and am wondering if there is any easy workaround.
An example of a program of this sort can be seen at https://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/differential-equations/half-life-calculator/

Here is my code:
[image]

How should I add numeric input to my Manipulate program?

Comment: Yeah, we have a close reason, "The answer to this question requires...the services of a professional consultant." Yours is a project that's rather broad and seems to call out for a consultant to do the work or work with you.  Not sure why someone thought the question deserves an upvote.  Maybe they will answer for you. (1) I can point you to `Variables[]` for determining the variables in the equation the user types. (2) You have a parsing problem: Mathematica naturally interprets "final velocity" as "final" times "velocity". It would be an easier thing to program if you required Mma syntax.

Comment: I can make the request specific. Given a relation with N variables X1.....XN, how can I make a calculator like emathhelps or WolframAlpha's Web Apps calculators to output a value? For a similar question see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/253772/how-to-create-an-interactive-solver-using-either-dynamic-dynamic-module-manipu.

Comment: You have to start somewhere. Try typing your ideas in Mathematica and ask specific questions. At the moment your post does not contain even a single line of code that we can work on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty version that I think should come close to what you're asking for. The handling of the variables and their localisation is not very sophisticated, but it should work for simple formulas:

```
Clear[a, b, c]
eq = c^2 == a^2 + b^2;
vars = Reduce`FreeVariables[eq]
sol = "";
Manipulate[
 Evaluate@Column@{HoldForm[Evaluate@eq], eq, Dynamic[sol]},
 Evaluate@Grid[
   Append[
    {HoldForm[#],
       InputField[
        Dynamic[#,
         Function[{val, expr},
          sol = "";
          If[val === Null, Clear[#], # = val]
          ]
         ], Number]} & /@ vars,
    With[{vars = vars, eq = eq},
     {
      Button["Solve",
       If[Count[vars, _Symbol] === 1,
        sol = Flatten@Solve[eq],
        sol = ""
        ],
       ImageSize -> Automatic,
       Method -> "Queued"
       ],
      SpanFromLeft
      }
     ]
    ]
   ]
]
```

To use it, give all input fields numerical values except for one. Then press solve.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)
```

Enter equation to be used (equation must use [`Equal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html) (`==`) rather than [`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) (`=`))

```
eqn = (Voltage == Current*Resistance);

vars = Variables[Level[eqn, {-1}]];

Manipulate[
 Column[{
   StringForm["Equation: ``", eqn], "",
   Reduce[eqn, var, domain],
   Manipulate @@ {
     Reduce[eqn, var, domain],
     Sequence @@ ({#, 1} & /@ DeleteCases[vars, var]),
     Paneled -> False,
     AppearanceElements -> None}}],
 Row[{
   Control[{{var, vars[[1]], "Solve for"}, vars}],
   Spacer[25],
   Control[{{domain, Reals, "Domain"}, {PositiveReals, NonNegativeReals, 
      Reals, Complexes, PositiveIntegers, NonNegativeIntegers, Integers}}]}]]
```

[image]