# How to make an interactive solver function?

Tags: functions, physics, interactive

I am working on creating a function that takes in any physics equation as a string and converts it to an equation that I will then paste into an interactive interface as asked here: [How to make an interactive calculator for any mathematical relation?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/257779/how-to-make-an-interactive-calculator-for-any-mathematical-relation). I am implementing the first answer as a function that accepts any physics equation as a string and does two things before replacing the example of a^2+b^2==c^2.

First I want to replace any instance of "=" with "==" except for an instance of "==". The goal of this is to make a user-friendly function if the user enters an equation with incorrect programming syntax. I will then convert it to an expression.

Second, after it has been converted to an expression I will extract the symbols from the equation using this code, which I got from [How to find all symbols in an expression and perform an operation on them?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51919/how-to-find-all-symbols-in-an-expression-and-perform-an-operation-on-them).

```
Symbols[x_String] := 
 DeleteDuplicates@Cases[ToExpression[x], _Symbol, Infinity]
```

The function for the first program is as follows:

```
StringReplace["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(a\), \
\(2\)]\)+\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(b\), \
\(2\)]\)==\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(c\), \(2\)]\)", 
 Except[{"=="}, "="] -> "=="]
```

I am trying to base my code off this example

```
StringReplace["the cat in the hat", 
 Except[Characters["aeiou"], "c"] -> ""]
```

Unfortunately, this causes an error:
[image]
I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

EDIT:
I have my attempt here: https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/burbery1/Published/Interactive%20Solver%20Function.nb
In the process I came across two more unexpected hurdles: if the variable the user is solving for was already defined in a previous call of Interactive Solver or another piece of program that already executed, the symbol is regarded as a numerical value and not a variable.

The second problem is that the InteractiveSolver function returns a list of Null values when I run it for some reason.

I tried some code provided as an answer to this question and encountered the following error:
[image]

Comment: Except is not accepted as a valid string pattern. As a way around, you could first replace all "==" by "=" and then replace all "=" by "==".

Comment: The function `Symbols` will return symbolic numeric constants as well as variables, e.g., look at the result of `Symbols["Pi*x + E"]`. Either modify the definition to `Symbols[x_String] := DeleteDuplicates@Cases[ToExpression[x], _Symbol?(!NumericQ[#]&), Infinity]` or use `Symbols[x_String] := Variables[Level[x, {-1}]]`

Comment: I am wondering if I should attach code in the form of a cloud notebook link or paste it directly in Stack Exchange or both. I have a little more than a page of code if you include the code in the question.

Comment: `Interpreter[]` might be fast enough for you: `parse = Interpreter["MathFormula"]; parse["a=b^2"]`. Parsing takes a little less than a second, so it's not fast.

Comment: I don't quite understand how the Interpreter capability of Mathematica can be used to turn any string with only one equations sign into an expression with an equality checking expression (==) instead of assignment (=). Can you provide an example or explain a little bit more how the Interpreter can help me accomplish my goal?

Comment: Why is the output of `Manipulate` labeled `In[5]` in the image? It isn't from executing the code I posted. It looks like you bypassed the `CellContext -> Cell` function. Just remove that option if you want to use it in some other way, but it puts all nonlocal symbols in the ``Global` `` context. -- I guess you hit shift-enter, which evaluates the output and creates a second, new one.  You shouldn't do that in `Manipulate`. Maybe there's some way to prevent it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, my take on the big problem. I'm not particularly interested in parsing strings, so I can delete if this is unhelpful.

```
(*"
 *  Calculator
"*)
CellPrint@
 ExpressionCell[
  Manipulate[
   Column[{
     (* displays some data for inspection *)
     Dynamic@{var, formula},
     Dynamic@Quiet[
       (* TBD:check input/output of Solve *)
       With[{sol = Solve[ReleaseHold@formula, var]},
        With[{sol0 = 
           sol /. Thread[freevariables -> value /@ freevariables]},
         value[var] = var /. Last[sol0];(* last sol *)
         Grid@Transpose@{sol, sol0} /. Rule -> Equal
         ]],
       {Power::infy}],
     (* parameter inputs *)
     Grid@Transpose@{
        freevariables,
        InputField[Dynamic@value@#] & /@ freevariables}
     }],
   
   {{formula, formula}, (* user input = held expression *)
    InputField[Dynamic[formula,
       ({formula, variables, var} = parseFormula[#];
         Clear[value];
         (value[#] = 1) & /@ variables;
         freevariables = DeleteCases[variables, var];
         ) &],
      Hold@Expression] &},
   {{var, var}, Dynamic@variables, SetterBar, TrackingFunction -> (
      (var = #;
        freevariables = DeleteCases[variables, var]) &)},
   {{variables, variables}, None},
   {{freevariables, freevariables}, None},
   {{parseFormula, parseFormula}, None},
   {{value, value}, None},(* stores values of parameters *)
   
   Initialization :> (
     (* utility (parses held expression) *)
     parseFormula // ClearAll;
     parseFormula[f_] := Module[{myformula, myvars, myvar},
       myformula = 
        f /. {Set | SetDelayed | Rule | RuleDelayed -> Equal,
          Null -> $Failed}; (* TBD: Handle user error *)
       myvars = Reduce`FreeVariables[ReleaseHold@myformula];
       myvar = Replace[{myformula, myvars},
         {{Hold[v_ == _] /; MemberQ[myvars, v], _} :> v,
          {_, {a_, ___}} :> a,
          {_, v_} :> v (* TBD: Handle user error *)
          }];
       myformula = Replace[myformula,
         {eq : Hold[_Equal] :> eq,
          Hold[x_] /; Internal`WouldBeNumericQ[x, Evaluate@myvars] :>
           (myvar = $ans; 
            PrependTo[myvars, $ans];
            Hold[$ans == x]),
          form_ :> (myvars = myvar = $Failed; form)
          }]; (* TBD: Handle user error *)
       {myformula, myvars, myvar}
       ];
     (* init *)
     {formula, variables, var} = 
      parseFormula[ToExpression["a^2+b^2==c^2", StandardForm, Hold]];
     freevariables = DeleteCases[variables, var];
     (value[#] = 1) & /@ variables;
     )
   ],
  "Output",
  CellContext -> Cell]
```

[image]

Comment: If I try to change the equation or relation inside the box I get an error that I would like to display in a screenshot but don't know how to.

Comment: @PeterBurbery What did you type? When I type "a^2 == b^2 - c^2", I get no error.

Comment: When I type "a^2=b^2-c^2" I get an error because it is an assignment expression and I would like to make it convert any assignment expressions into equality testing expressions.

Comment: @PeterBurbery I get no error if I enter "a^2=b^2-c^2".  The code converts `=` (`Set`) to `==` (`Equal`) when the formula is parsed. It also converts `A -> b h` to `A == b h`. Not that a student would think of that, but it's a sort of like an assignment (a substitution `Rule` technically), so I threw that in. Unfortunately (?) `E = m c^2` gets converted to the base of the natural logarithm and `E=mc^2` is in terms the single variable `mc` squared.

Comment: I was pressing Shift+Enter every time instead of Enter. It is working now.

Comment: How do I force it to evaluate numerically like NSolve or NSolveValues?

Comment: @PeterBurbery There are probably several ways. One might be to wrap `sol0` in `N` in the output: `N[sol0]`.  Another might be to use `NSolve` instead of `Solve`.